# How to unit test the grid is displayed in a plot done with matplotlib

Tags: unit-testing, matplotlib

I have a method to create a plot with matplotlib.
The grid should be displayed or not based on a boolean passed as argument.
Is there a way in a unit test only this part of the plot, to make sure this is working properly? Is there a way to get the plot definition and see the grid is 'on'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if `any()` gridlines are visible (or `all()` if preferred):

```py
>>> fig, ax = plt.subplots()
>>> ax.grid(True) # enable all gridlines
>>> any(line.get_visible() for line in ax.get_xgridlines() + ax.get_ygridlines())
True
```

```py
>>> ax.grid(False) # disable all gridlines
>>> any(line.get_visible() for line in ax.get_xgridlines() + ax.get_ygridlines())
False
```

```py
>>> ax.grid(False)
>>> ax.get_xgridlines()[0].set_visible(True) # enable 1 gridline
>>> any(line.get_visible() for line in ax.get_xgridlines() + ax.get_ygridlines())
True
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the difference between:

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

any(line.get_visible() for line in ax.get_xgridlines() + ax.get_ygridlines())

and

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.grid(True)  

any(line.get_visible() for line in ax.get_xgridlines() + ax.get_ygridlines())

Comment: @ValérieGelbgras sorry, can you explain a little more? are you saying both of them return `True` for you?

Comment: If I do a plot and do not use ax.grid(True), get_visible() returns true for all lines. I tried to check the lines before and after doing ax.grid(True), I do not additional lines.

Comment: @ValérieGelbgras what's your `matplotlib.__version__`? i'm not able to reproduce. this code returns False for me: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; fig, ax = plt.subplots(); any(line.get_visible() for line in ax.get_xgridlines() + ax.get_ygridlines())`

Comment: I attached a screenshot in the question. I am using the version 3.0.3 and python 3.7.8

Comment: @ValérieGelbgras ah ok, i can reproduce on matplotlib 3.0.3. are you able to upgrade matplotlib?

Comment: it works with a more recent version of matplotlib. Thank you very much.